find number of subsequences which are greater than another string
Given two strings s of length m and another string t of length n, count how many subsequences of s are greater than t

A sequence p is called greater than another sequence q if it satisfies
below cases:
a) p[i] > q[i] at the first position where p and q differ, or
b) |p| > |q| and q is a prefix of p (where |p| denotes the length of password p).

Example:
s ="bab"
t ="ab"
Result = 5
Explanation:
Valid subsequences of s which are greater than t are
"b"
"ba"
"bb"
"bab"
"b"

constraints:
length of s 1 to 10^5
length of t 1 to 100
The length of t can be more than the length of s also with valid combinations.
I solved it using a recursive approach but it is taking O(2^n * n) time complexity.
public class Main {
    private static final int MOD = 1_000_000_007;

    private static void subsequence(String s, int index, String current, List<String> subsequences) {
        if (index == s.length()) {
            if (!current.isEmpty()) {
                subsequences.add(current);
            }
            return;
        }
        subsequence(s, index + 1, current, subsequences);
        subsequence(s, index + 1, current + s.charAt(index), subsequences);
    }

    private static boolean isGreater(String s1, String t) {
        int len1 = s1.length();
        int len2 = t.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(len1, len2); i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) > t.charAt(i)) {
                return true;
            } else if (s1.charAt(i) < t.charAt(i)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return len1 > len2;
    }

    public static int solve(String s, String t) {
        List<String> subsequences = new ArrayList<>();
        subsequence(s, 0, "", subsequences);

        int count = 0;
        for (String e : subsequences) {
            if (isGreater(e, t)) {
                count = (count + 1) % MOD;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(solve("aba", "ab")); // Expected: 3
        System.out.println(solve("bab", "ab")); // Expected: 5
        System.out.println(solve("wrrmkhds", "bebbjvcgzlwtbvasphvm")); // Expected: 255
        System.out.println(solve("o", "h"));   // Expected: 1
    }
}

How can this be solved in less time complexity?

It looks like your implementation is generating every single subsequence to be compared between s and t then incrementing the count accordingly. While that would give the correct answer, the task requests only for you to count the number of such subsequences. As a hint, for these sort of counting problems it is often the case that the intended solution doesn't involve enumeration. I'd suggest coming up with a small example and determining a formula (could be a recursive one) that computes the desired count, then verifying it works against your test case(s) before coding.

If your code works, but you want to improve it, it may be a candidate for Code Review .  By the way, if this problem has a web page, it would be polite to include a link to that page.

You can use a recurrence relation, and implement that with dynamic programming.
If we consider a suffix of , starting at index  and a suffix of , starting at index  (let's use the notation [:] and [:] for those suffixes) then we have a smaller problem to solve, namely how many subsequences of the first suffix are greater than the second suffix. We can use this result for the bigger problem.
If we want to know the solution for [:] and [:], then we have a few scenarios:

If [:] is empty (i.e.  ≥ ), then there are 0 subsequences.

Otherwise, we can split the count of subsequences in two groups:

Subsequences that exclude []
This count is equal to the solution for [+1:] and [:] (we just removed [] from the input)

Subsequences that include []

If  ≥  or [] > [], then the following characters of  don't matter anymore, and we can freely chose which characters of [+1:] to include or not. This represents 2-1- possible subsequences, all of which start with [].

When [] = [], then the count of subsequences is given by the solution for [+1:] and [+1:]

Otherwise (when [] < []), we made an invalid choice, and so there are 0 subsequences to count for this scenario.






More formally, define  as the length of ,  as the length of  and ,  as the number of subsequences of [:] that are greater than [:]. Then:

,  = 0, when  ≥ 

,  = +1,  + 2-1-, when otherwise  ≥  or [] > []

,  = +1,  + +1, +1, when otherwise [] = []

,  = 0, otherwise


In the end, we need the value for 0, 0
To implement this, we could use a bottom-up approach, starting with an empty suffix of  (i.e.  = ), and then grow that suffix (decreasing ). For each suffix consider  decreasing from  to 0. As ,  only depends directly on +1,  and +1, +1, we don't actually need to store that whole matrix , but can suffice with keeping two consecutive rows of that matrix in memory only.
Here is an implementation:
    public static int solve(String s, String t) {
        int m = s.length();
        int n = t.length();
        
        int[] dp = new int[n+1];
        int[] dpPrev;
        
        for (int i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) { // Grow the suffix of s that is considered
            // Take a copy to have a reference to previous results (for smaller s suffix)
            dpPrev = dp.clone(); 
            // There are 2^(length of s[i:]) - 1 non-empty subsequences 
            //     when t[j:] is empty (j == n):
            dp[n] = 2 * dp[n] + 1;
            // Add the cases where s[i] is included in the subsequences
            for (int j = n - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                int cmp = Character.compare(s.charAt(i), t.charAt(j));
                       // Add the count of all subsequences of s[s+1:] (+1 for empty one)
                dp[j] += cmp >  0 ? dpPrev[n] + 1 
                       // Add the count of subsequences of s[i+1:] greater than t[j+1:]
                       : cmp == 0 ? dpPrev[j+1]
                       : 0;
            }
        } 
        return dp[0];
    }

NB: your code had a constant 1_000_000_007, which was not mentioned in your question. I assume it will be no problem for you to incorporate the requirement that relates to that constant. I preferred to keep it out so to focus on the question.

Thank you, but the answer is failing for some test cases, for example solve("wrrmkhds", "bebbjvcgzlwtbvasphvm") expected is 255 but the above code is returning 0, also for solve("o", "h") expected is 1 but the above code is returning 0. can you please check.

There was an issue with cmp. Fixed now. The two examples you have given in your comment now return the expected result. Can you please share where we can test the program?

This question was asked during an interview with hackerrank platform, so I was given only a few test cases which I posted here.

Now this updated answer is failing first 2 test cases which I posted `solve("aba", "ab") // Expected: 3, but above answer is returning 1
solve("bab", "ab") // Expected: 5, but above answer is returning 0`

Can you give the link?

sorry, I don't have a link for it

OK. I see I hadn't fixed the cmp issue correctly. Updated. Tested for the four cases you have given.

It seems like you can just create an auxiliary list with the indices of the letters that are smaller than t[i]. Call this list x.
Then use simple math to determine how many subsequences you can form using the ranges between the indices in x.
In your example, x=[1]. So, we have the first closed range [0-0] that can form 1 subsequence. The second range is [2-2], which gives us the range [0-2]. You can form 3C1+3C2+3C3=6 subsequences, but you’ll have to subtract the subsequences for [0-0] (already counted) and [1-1] (not included). So, that gives us 1+4=5 subsequences.

I'm not able to understand the answer, can you please add more details
